# What statistical test do I use to compare 2 running means?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have measured the learning rates of two neural network models, and now I have the average reward plotted against time, for both models. What statistical test can I use to compare the 2 lines to see if there is a significant difference or not?

The models are both the same, but are initialized differently to see whether the average reward against time changes.

Answer (score 1):

More formally, you can use [ANCOVA](http://www.biostathandbook.com/ancova.html#:%7E:text=Use%20analysis%20of%20covariance%20)

Or a quick way would be to take the difference of the learning rates and then doing linear regression to see if the slope is statistically significant to be not 0 (T-test), Showed below:

[image]